# PHP, MySQL statement results in ZERO rows

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

hope someone can help me.

i have a very simple prepared SELECT statment in PHP:

```
        $query_select = ("SELECT * FROM companies where user_name = ? ");
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_select);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_name);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

in `companies` table I have several rows with the $user_name i`m trying to query. But i still get 0 rows as a result.

The strange thing is that the non PREPARED version works:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM companies WHERE user_name="'.$user_name.'"'; 
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$count= $result->num_rows;
echo "Aantal: ".$count;
```

So my question is, does anyone know why the prepared version returns ZERO and the non prepared version returns the correct number of rows?

Comment: add `echo 'Error: ' . $stmt->error();` after execute and see if there are any errors

Comment: Thanks for helping, but your syntax suggestions occurs a ftal error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::error() i

Comment: I see i should remove the () after error()   http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: oke now it worked: I added this:  echo "Error: " .$stmt->error."Number of rows: ".$count      And the browser shows no error and still 0 rows: Error: Number of rows: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to your code between execute and num_rows statement.

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

You have to store it before counting it.

Answer (score 0):

For mysqli prepared statements, you must take an additional step: storing the result.

Try this:

```
$query_select = ("SELECT * FROM companies where user_name = ? ");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_select);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result(); // <-- new line
$count = $stmt->num_rows;
```

Comment: @rjdown: I've never encountered `store_result()` before (I use PDO instead anyway). Is this necessary to retrieve row results from the query too, or is it just for counting rows? Seems that this work should be done by `execute()`!

Comment: @halfer for resultsets, you'd need to use get_result instead e.g. `$stmt->execute(); $result = $stmt->get_result(); print_r($result->fetch_assoc());`

Comment: Thanks! Phew... PDO does seem easier!

Comment: PDO is better in every way I can think of :)

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to bind the result:

`/* bind result variables */
$stmt->bind_result($district);`

Full example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)